# Listings - Adjust different indentations to the same look

Tags: listings

I have a bunch of code snippets and they look like these guys:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]

% snippet 1
\begin{lstlisting}
List list = new ArrayList();
\end{lstlisting}

% snippet 2
\begin{lstlisting}
    List list = new ArrayList();
\end{lstlisting}

% snippet 3
\begin{lstlisting}
        List list = new ArrayList() {
         // ...
        }
\end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Snippet 1 has no indentation.

Snippet 2 has an indentation of one tab.

Snippet 3 has an indentation of two tabs, and the inner of the code block is indented by one space extra.

So, now, I am looking for an opportunity to let them look identically regarding the indentation.

I've tried to "kill" the tabs by

```
\lstset{
    tabsize=0
}
```

but getting the error `Package Listings Error: Strict positive integer expected. }`.

My second concern would be, how I could extend the indentation of one space in snippet 3 by e.g. four spaces.
Is there something like

```
\literate{<begin_of_line>\ }{\ \ \ \ }{4}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To auto-gobble text in `listings`, you may need Martin Scharrer's `lstautogobble` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\lstset{autogobble}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]

% snippet 1
\begin{lstlisting}
List list = new ArrayList();
\end{lstlisting}

% snippet 2
\begin{lstlisting}
    List list = new ArrayList();
\end{lstlisting}

% snippet 3
\begin{lstlisting}
        List list = new ArrayList() {
         // ...
        }
\end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks. But it gobbles only tabs, right? How can I extend the one space by four spaces (see "my second concern" at the post). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mrbela That is a new question. Please don't ask two different topics on the same question.

Comment: Allright. I will begin a new topic.